# Cakephp inheritance of model associations

Tags: cakephp, inheritance, model-associations

If I create a Model Car with some associations:
hasOne Driver
hasMany Wheel
And then create a Model Truck extending Car with

```
class Truck extends Car { ... }
```

is it normal that the associations from Car are not inherited from Truck?
What are the possibilities to inherit model associations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is PHP related; your custom classes will behave the same way regardless of anything in cakephp.  Class inheritance in CakePHP is completely depended on How your classes are written.  Inheritance is an important part of cakephp; the framework is very much object oriented.

Are you including the classes properly using App::uses() to load your car class into truck?

Answer (score 1):

The only way your `Truck` class will not inherit from the `Car` class is if you have defined the properties in the `Truck` class.

```
class Car extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array('Driver', ...);
}

class Truck extends Car {
    public $hasOne = array(); // now you have no hasOne relations
}
```